How would changing a folder that a symlink points to affect a running app?
I don't know how to search for this online.
I am doing regular deployments every week.
I have a folder structure like this
folder1/myApp_tps_20240928_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/myApp_otherProcs_20240928_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/myApp_otherProcs_20241005_DEV/<app_code_here>

myApp_tps_20240928_DEV and myApp_otherProcs_20241005_DEV contain the exact same code with myApp_otherProcs_20241005_DEV with a few code changes that I add during the week.
Tickerplant layer doesn't have to be restarted every week, in fact I would very much prefer not to bounce it too often (code affecting tickerplants rarely changes).
Code for other procs changes frequently and needs to be bounced regularly.
I would like to have a separation by date so that if something goes wrong, I can switch the symlink back and revert to previous version of my code.
This is what I would like to do:
folder1/myApp_20240928_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/myApp_20241005_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/myApp -> myApp_20241005_DEV (symlink)

In this situation, tp layer will still run code from myApp_20240928_DEV, but other procs will run code from myApp_20241005_DEV and when a tp is bounced it will start again from myApp_20241005_DEV. If there are schema changes we can manually bounce the tp to load new schemas etc.
Question 1: What will happen if I delete myApp_20240928_DEV even if tps are still running from that code?
Question 2: Would it be more advisable to have a folder structure like this:
folder1/myApp_20240928_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/myApp_20241005_DEV/<app_code_here>
folder1/tpLayer -> myApp_20240928_DEV 
folder1/nonTpLayer -> myApp_20240928_DEV 

I also considered having a new normalizers/feeds layer that will be up all the time so I can bounce my app with no issues, but it would take quite a bit to develop and I am trying to avoid that.

Question 1: What will happen if I delete myApp_20240928_DEV even if tps are still running from that code?
A: Usually it is ok once the TP has started and initialized. However, it is good to check the code that the TP does not rely on any underlying code after initialization. Although it is not advisable to delete assemblies while it is in use, it is better to use the second method of symlinking.
Question 2: Would it be more advisable to have a folder structure like this:
A: Yes, it is advisable to have a standard path to your processes and a separate one to the assemblies (code). Then symlink them for versioning. When you update the symlink path, the running process should be still running the old version until it is bounced to pick up the new (symlinked) version.

so for the second option I would have "duplicate" code. The contents of these folders are identical with the new version only containing the code changes since the previous deployments. I was hoping of not having separate folders for tpLayers / nonTpLayers. so with the symlinks ... you mean it is better to have a tpLayer and a nonTpLyaer symlink or just a symlink to the latest version of the code myApp -> ... ?

@flavio I meant it is better to have a symlink to the latest version of the code. Unless if your code base is so big to have duplicates then maybe it needs to be looked at. Having duplicate assemblies (code) is usually not a problem if your system cleans up assemblies that are not being used. If your tpLayers/nonTpLayers are in the same project, then I would advise not to separate them during versioning/deployment. Alternatively, you can split up your project into core/non-core layers. Then your regular deployments will only update the non-core layers.

Separating tpLayers/nonTpLayers are in the same project may also be more susceptible to human error, make deployment more complicated and it may be difficult to identify what versions which layer is actually running on unless your process logs it.
